# Java Servlet: How can I retrieve selected radio button values?

Tags: java, servlets, radio-button

I have created a simple servlet in which a user will be presented with 2 questions, answering either true or false. My problem lies in retrieving the answers selected by the user.

Code:

```
            out.println("<FORM ACTION=\"Game\" METHOD = \"POST\">" +

        "<b>Question 1: Are you over the age of 25? </b><br> <br>" +

        "<input type = \"radio\" name = \"Q1rad1\" onclick = \"getAnswer('a')\"> True " +
        "<input type = \"radio\" name = \"Q1rad2\" onclick = \"getAnswer('b')\"> False<br>" +

        "<br><br><b>Question 2: Are you from earth?</b><br> <br>" +

        "<input type = \"radio\" name = \"Q2rad1\" onclick = \"getAnswer('a')\"> True " +
        "<input type = \"radio\" name = \"Q2rad2\" onclick = \"getAnswer('b')\"> False<br>" +

        out.println("<Center><INPUT  TYPE=\"SUBMIT\"></Center>");


        );
```

Each question has 2 radio buttons, Q1rad1 & Q2rad2, for answering True or False. How can i know the value selected by each user when the submit button is pressed.

I understand it may be more efficient when using Javascript but for the purposes of this problem I must be using servlets.

Comment: Oh no, why aren't you using a JSP to generate the HTML?

Answer (score 15):

You have to define the value you want to retrieve when the radio button is selected

The *value* setting defines what will be submitted if checked.

The *name* setting tells which group of radio buttons the field belongs to. When you select one button, all other buttons in the same group are unselected.

```html
<input type="radio" name="Q2" onclick="getAnswer('b')" value="b">
<input type="radio" name="Q2" onclick="getAnswer('a')" value="a">
```

In your Servlet which will recieve the request you'll have something like

```java
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // get the value of the button group 
    String q2 = request.getParameter("Q2");
    // compare selected value 
    if ("a".equals(q2)) {
    ...
    }
    ...
    
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You haven't named your radio buttons correctly. Each radio option for the same question need the same name attribute. Also, you should have a `value` attribute on each `<input type="radio">`. I'm not sure you need the `onclick` handler at all. You should also have a `</form>` closer tag. Your form might look like this:

```
 out.println("<form action=\"Game\" method=\"POST\">" +

    "<b>Question 1: Are you over the age of 25? </b><br> <br>" +

    "<input type = \"radio\" name = \"Q1\" value=\"True\"> True " +
    "<input type = \"radio\" name = \"Q1\" value=\"False\"> False<br>" +

    "<br><br><b>Question 2: Are you from earth?</b><br> <br>" +

    "<input type = \"radio\" name = \"Q2\" value=\"True\"> True " +
    "<input type = \"radio\" name = \"Q2\" value=\"False\"> False<br>" +

    "<Center><INPUT  TYPE=\"SUBMIT\"></Center>" +

    "</form>"
    );
```

And then in the `doPost()` method of servlet that handles the form submission, you can access the values using `request.getParameter()`. Something like this:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String q1 = request.getParameter("Q1");
    String q2 = request.getParameter("Q2");
    // more processing code...
}
```

Comment: So I am clear, what values are stored in String variables for q1 and q2 on calling the getParameter()?

Comment: @Jnanathan: The value you get is whatever is in the `value` attribute of the `<input type="radio">`. I've updated my answer to include `value` attributes.

Answer (score 3):

Give the same name to the radios of the same question, and set different values.
Look at this [page](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp).

Then in the request you will get a parameter with the name of the radio group and the value selected.
After submit the servlet the receives the post can use:

```
String value = request.getParameter("radioName");
```

Answer (score 1):

For your HTML Code the below lines are enough

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res){
String q1 = request.getParameter("Q1");
String q2 = request.getParameter("Q2");`
}
```

For example, Considering your HTML Code.

If Q1 is pressed

> "TRUE"

then it would be our "Input" in Servlet.